# How to use actions in SceneKit Editor

Tags: ios, scenekit

This is probably really dumb. I've been playing around with SceneKit Editor. There is a bunch of **actions** in the Object Library. How do I use them? I've been dragging them to all possible nodes, stuff in scene, I even tried to place them in code. Nothing. They always snap back to the Object Library. I added a screenshot so we all know what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the lower part of the scene editor you can open the action editor. After selecting an node you'll be able to drag and drop actions in its timeline.

[image: Action Editor in the SceneKit Editor]

You can find a demo of the action editor in the "[Enhancements to SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=606)" session.